# GraphLab Create / Canopy - Runtime Exception. Unable to evaluate lambdas. -

Tags: python, python-2.7, canopy, graphlab

I am using GraphLab Create  + Enthought Canopy Express installed on Win 7 Pro

```
(Canopy 64bit) C:\Users\kittuNnivvi>python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.9 | 64-bit | (default, Jul  1 2015, 03:41:50) [MSC v
.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

and here is how I installed GraphLab Create

```
(Canopy 64bit) C:\Users\kittuNnivvi>pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https:/
/get.dato.com/GraphLab-Create/1.6.1/axx@xxx.xxx/AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-...-67E6/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz
```

I am using it in `IPython Notebook` inside `Canopy Editor`.

Following commands work.

```
sf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('people-example.csv')

sf['Country'].show  

def transform_country(country):
    if country == "USA":
        return 'United States'
    else:
        return country

transform_country('USA')
```

Whereas when I run the following code -

```
sf['Country'] = sf['Country'].apply(transform_country)
```

I am getting Runtime Exception

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-58b2d3ea026a> in <module>()
----> 1 sf['Country'].apply(transform_country)

C:\Users\kittuNnivvi\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\graphlab\data_structures\sarray.pyc in apply(self, fn, dtype, skip_undefined, seed)
   1624 
   1625         with cython_context():
-> 1626             return SArray(_proxy=self.__proxy__.transform(fn, dtype, skip_undefined, seed))
   1627 
   1628 

C:\Users\kittuNnivvi\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\graphlab\cython\context.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
     47             if not self.show_cython_trace:
     48                 # To hide cython trace, we re-raise from here
---> 49                 raise exc_type(exc_value)
     50             else:
     51                 # To show the full trace, we do nothing and let exception propagate

RuntimeError: Runtime Exception. Unable to evaluate lambdas. lambda workers did not start
```

I am new GraphLab Create - please help. It does appear to caused by enviornment setting. I have been reading other posts here in this forum.

I ran `graphlab.get_runtime_config()` - among others it returned the value for 
`GRAPHLAB_CACHE_FILE_LOCATIONS`. here is the a portion from the server_log file.

```
1444236358 : ERROR:    (operator():272): Min value not available for a non-numeric column
1444236358 : INFO:     (commit_global_if_out_of_date:515): num elements: 0  rows_processed: 7   time:0.005
1444236631 : INFO:     (new_cache:157): Cache Utilization:139264
1444236631 : INFO:     (delete_path_impl:299): Deleting cache://tmp/000048.0000
1444236631 : INFO:     (delete_path_impl:299): Deleting cache://tmp/000048.sidx
1444236632 : INFO:     (transform:396): Function entry
1444236632 : INFO:     (spawn_worker:40): Start lambda worker at ipc://C:/Users/KITTUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/graphlab-kittuNnivvi/51684/11a47be5-ab46-462f-a895-329814281fa7 using binary: C:/Users\kittuNnivvi\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\graphlab\pylambda_worker.exe
1444236632 : INFO:     (spawn_worker:40): Start lambda worker at ipc://C:/Users/KITTUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/graphlab-kittuNnivvi/51684/31e984ce-a9ac-4566-b7be-e38f01086483 using binary: C:/Users\kittuNnivvi\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\graphlab\pylambda_worker.exe
1444236632 : INFO:     (spawn_worker:40): Start lambda worker at ipc://C:/Users/KITTUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/graphlab-kittuNnivvi/51684/74ab5626-299c-4c9d-98a2-4eda85468f0d using binary: C:/Users\kittuNnivvi\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\graphlab\pylambda_worker.exe
1444236632 : INFO:     (spawn_worker:40): Start lambda worker at ipc://C:/Users/KITTUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/graphlab-kittuNnivvi/51684/a53be544-851a-4a15-bf47-ba74f74b2857 using binary: C:/Users\kittuNnivvi\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\graphlab\pylambda_worker.exe
1444236633 : INFO:     (launch:76): Launched process with pid: 46684
1444236633 : INFO:     (launch:76): Launched process with pid: 57468
1444236633 : INFO:     (launch:76): Launched process with pid: 47452
1444236633 : INFO:     (launch:76): Launched process with pid: 57372
1444236668 : INFO:     (spawn_worker:71): Fail connecting to worker at ipc://C:/Users/KITTUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/graphlab-kittuNnivvi/51684/31e984ce-a9ac-4566-b7be-e38f01086483. Status: Communication Failure. Retry: 1
1444236668 : INFO:     (spawn_worker:71): Fail connecting to worker at ipc://C:/Users/KITTUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/graphlab-kittuNnivvi/51684/74ab5626-299c-4c9d-98a2-4eda85468f0d. Status: Communication Failure. Retry: 1
1444236668 : INFO:     (spawn_worker:71): Fail connecting to worker at ipc://C:/Users/KITTUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/graphlab-kittuNnivvi/51684/11a47be5-ab46-462f-a895-329814281fa7. Status: Communication Failure. Retry: 1
1444236668 : INFO:     (spawn_worker:71): Fail connecting to worker at ipc://C:/Users/KITTUN~1/AppData/Local/Temp/graphlab-kittuNnivvi/51684/a53be544-851a-4a15-bf47-ba74f74b2857. Status: Communication Failure. Retry: 1
1444236669 : ERROR:    (spawn_worker:54): Lambda worker process terminated unexpectedly
1444236669 : ERROR:    (spawn_worker:54): Lambda worker process terminated unexpectedly
1444236669 : ERROR:    (operator():141): Fail launching lambda worker.
1444236669 : ERROR:    (operator():141): Fail launching lambda worker.
1444236669 : ERROR:    (spawn_worker:54): Lambda worker process terminated unexpectedly
1444236669 : ERROR:    (operator():141): Fail launching lambda worker.
1444236669 : ERROR:    (spawn_worker:54): Lambda worker process terminated unexpectedly
1444236669 : ERROR:    (operator():141): Fail launching lambda worker.
1444236669 : ERROR:    (operator():152): Unable to evaluate lambdas. lambda workers did not start
1444237544 : INFO:     (construct_from_csvs:115): Construct sframe from csvs at C:\edu\ml\people-example.csv
1444237544 : INFO:     (construct_from_csvs:122): Parsing config:
    comment_char: 
    continue_on_failure: 1
    delimiter: ,
    double_quote: 1
    escape_char: \
    line_terminator: 

    na_values: ["NA"]
    output_columns: []
    quote_char: "
    row_limit: 100
    skip_initial_space: 1
    skip_rows: 0
    store_errors: 0
    use_header: 1
```

I could see three Python27.lib - they are identical in size.

Here is the output when run on my machine.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\python27.
zip', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\
canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\En
thought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\k
ittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.w
in-x86_64\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\C
anopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\kit
tuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win
-x86_64', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User', 'C:
\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-package
s', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-
packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\Us
er\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\En
thought\\Canopy\\User\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\
AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppDa
ta\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\\lib\\s
ite-packages', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\
appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\k
ittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.w
in-x86_64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\kittuNnivvi\\AppData\\Lo
cal\\Enthought\\Canopy\\App\\appdata\\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\\lib\\site-pa
ckages\\Pythonwin']
>>> print sys.exec_prefix
C:\Users\kittuNnivvi\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kittuNnivvi\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1
.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
>>>
```

Any inputs you may provide on how I troubleshoot this further will be very helpful.

Comment: When you did `pip install --upgrade ...`, what packages were upgraded? This might have broken some dependency relationships with existing Canopy package installations. Also, does graphlab have a runtime dependency on Cython? If it does, then you may need MS C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 (https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469260-Building-Python-extensions-with-Canopy)

Comment: When I did `pip freeze` I do not see `cython` listed. I do not yet know about gl having a rt dependency on Cython.

Comment: Any news? Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I removed Canopy - my interest was in GraphLab Create.There is an AMI with GraphLab Create I am using.